# Issue retrieving the file location

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to retrieve a file `feedback.php` and I have node.js installed.
on localhost, I'm listening to port:3000 `app.listen(3000)`

this is the file location

[image: Filezilla Directory Image]

Whenever i try to call this file i get:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

I also tried localhost:3000/feedback.php and i get **Cannot GET /feedback.php**

Feedback.php is being called from public -> js -> feedback.js

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "feedback.php",//===PHP file name and directory====
            data:{like: like},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            //Success Message == 'Title', 'Message body', Last one leave as it is
```

I don't know if it's of any relevance but I don't have any `index.html` else an `index.ejs` inside the **view** folder.

Comment: You need PHP compiler to execute PHP files.

Comment: PHP Compiler has to be installed on Server?

Comment: Yes, Node.js is a runtime for running JavaScript files.

Comment: Do you have any links for me to look up?

Comment: Take a look at WAMP stack https://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Currently Installed Packages on the VPS Server
Contains Apache 2.4, PHP 7.1, PHP 7.2, PHP 7.3, and Ruby 2.4 i don't think that PHP is missing